# How to double the collector current of a BJT in LTSpice?

Tags: bjt, ltspice, pnp, modeling

I am trying to model a multi-collector lateral PNP in LTSpice.  The link here suggests to put 2 PNP transistors in parallel and split up the IS into two parts.

http://pallen.ece.gatech.edu/Academic/ECE_6412/Spring_2003/L210-DCAnalysisof741-2UP.pdf

Sounds easy, right?  I have been playing with the LTSpice model statement:

.MODEL Local PNP(IS=1E-16 BF=200)

and change it to

.MODEL Local PNP(IS=2E-16 BF=200)

You would think that the change in IS would double the current... The PNP transistor operates in the active region, meaning EBJ is forward biased, BCJ is reverse biased.

Every equation in the book says: Ic = IS x exp(Veb/Vth) - so any change in IS should have an effect on the collector current.

What am I missing...?

Comment: So what actually DID happen when you changed Is - you forgot to mention that! And please embed a picture of your circuit.

Comment: The actual equations used to model the BJT are a little more complex than the active mode portion of the Ebers-Moll. LTspice supports MEXTRAM and a modified version of Gummel-Poon, memory serving. (More realistic.) You need to be aware, also, of the Early Effect as an early-order effect that is important, depending. But that said, in general, you will get about twice the collector current with twice the saturation current. That does work in LTSpice. What I want you to do is to post a minimal problematic schematic to illustrate your claim here. Prove the problem! I'll help then. Not before.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.hibbingfinancial.com/LTSPICE_PNP_Simulation.png)

Comment: I added an image (see above - hopefully the link works).  I am simulating just a single bias point.  It's a model with just beta in it and Is.  All other parameters are default (which typically means, it's turned off or ideal).  I measured the currents and voltages on each node and the emitter base diode is forward biased.  The base collector diode is reverse biased so that looks ok.  The beta is 100 and that comes out in the Ic/Ib ratio.  Alpha close to 1.  If I increase the Is from 1e-14 to 2e-14, I see some increase in Ic, but very little, not a doubling as I expected.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a UA741 opamp, then considerable effort went into the design to have the internal currents be largely immune to process and temperature variations, such as a doubling of Is.

Find the 741 bias circuit, and understand THAT, then adjust the currents.

Comment: Yes, its for the uA741.  However, as you see in the link, that design has a BJT with double collector.   As you can see in the link the way to model a double collector BJT is to use two BJTs with 0.25xIs for one and 0.75xIs for the other BJT.  So that seems straightforward.  But when I grab a BJT in LTSpice and change Is by a certain amount the colllector current does not follow as expected.  Something weird is going on.  I invite you to have a look at the first 3 pages of the pdf behind the link.  It’s from a professor at a university who has decades of experience teaching the ua741 in class.

Comment: What other SPICE bipolar model parameters are involved? Examine SPICE models for other bipolar transistors, and import into LTSPICE, and evaluate.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.hibbingfinancial.com/LTSPICE_PNP_Simulation.png)

Comment: I added an image (see above - hopefully the link works). I am simulating just a single bias point. It's a model with just beta in it and Is. All other parameters are default (which typically means, it's turned off or ideal). I measured the currents and voltages on each node and the emitter base diode is forward biased. The base collector diode is reverse biased so that looks ok. The beta is 100 and that comes out in the Ic/Ib ratio. Alpha close to 1. If I increase the Is from 1e-14 to 2e-14, I see some increase in Ic, but very little, not a doubling as I expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: My question is actually pretty simple... Why is it that Ic (collector current) doesn't double if I double Is?  In this particular bias regime, with everything set to ideal, one would expect Ic to double if Is doubles, right?  (Early effect is turned off, Rb=Re=Rc=0).  At some point, this expectation has to come out (2xIs --> 2x Ic)...

Answer (score 0):

Using the 2N2222 model as an example, to get the equivalent of 2x parallel transistors, include these parameters:

Is=2e-14
RB=5
RC=0.15
RE=0.1
IKF=0.6